# Random number onTouchEvent in Android

Tags: android, random, touch-event

I am planning to generate random number with touchevent on android platform

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" touched " );
        //int test = rand.nextInt(5);

        System.out.println(" touched " + rand.nextInt(5));
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

however, when I touch the screen, it shows me following error "The application has stopped unexpectedly". not sure what's the problem with the code. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing return super.onTouchEvent(event); to return false; And write if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks divoom12. I changed that, however, I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its not exactly like yours, but works:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
    {
            Random r = new Random();
            int i1=r.nextInt(80-65) + 65; // from 65, to 80
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

`}));`

Hope this helps.